# allow file upload with a variable filename

Tags: php

I use a switch to check files for their file names during upload.
Only files with specific names may be forwarded. However, it only works if the name is fixed.
Is it possible that my switch can also accept variable names?
Here is an example.
I expect a file every day that starts with the name **filesource** but always ends with a new date like **filesource-2023_05_20.csv**. The format to be accepted would therefore be **filesource-YYYY_MM_DD.csv**.

Here my code actually:

```
switch($infoFichier['filename']){
    // Here my variable filename
   
    case 'filesource*':
        $newFileName = 'filesource*.csv'; 
        $updir = PATH.'/files/';
        $updirst = PATH.'/files/depot/';
        $uploadfile = $updir.'depot/'.$newFileName;
        $fileName = $_FILES['fic_demande']['name'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['fic_demande']['type'];            
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fic_demande']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
            header('location:depot/import.php?file='.$newFileName.'&path='.$updirst.'&type='.$fileType);
        }
        break;
```

Is there a solution that my switch could accept this fileformat?

THX in advance.

Comment: You could use Regular Expressions

Comment: Should probably rather not use a switch for this to begin with. (Yes, `switch(true)` with "dynamic" case conditions is possible in PHP, but IMHO rather ugly.)

Comment: `$newFileName = 'filesource*.csv';` - that would not work on a Windows system though, `*` is not allowed in file names there.

Comment: @ADyson, Thx. have you an exemple for me? I dont know how to use it

Comment: `switch` is great for testing something against a (usually small) finite list, but it comes with several limitations, including, as you’ve found, the inability to perform more complicated tests on the input. The [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) has an example of using `switch(true){}`, but as noted, some people find it ugly, and you might have to rewrite a lot to support it. My recommendation would be to just use an `if`, either before this whole thing, or probably better in the `default` case, and `str_starts_with` could be used.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/ is one good place to start learning, if you're not familiar with regular expressions. But if you don't actually care whether the end of the filename is a valid date or not, and are just looking for filenames which start with `filesource`, then you can do what Chris Haas' comment above suggests, and simply use `str_starts_with` to test it.

Answer (score 1):

i have it figure out with substring.
I add this before the switch :

```
$infoFichier = pathinfo($_FILES['fic_demande']['name']);

$sm_dt_vl = substr($infoFichier['filename'],13);
$flsrc = 'filesource-'.$sm_dt_vl;

case $flsrc :
            $newFileName = $flsrc.'.csv';
```

Thanks everybody for your ideas and Help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you assign the variable `$newFileName` as `$newFileName = 'filesource-'.date('Y_m_d').'.csv';`

```
switch($infoFichier['filename']){
   
case 'filesource*':
    $newFileName = 'filesource-'.date('Y_m_d').'.csv';
    $updir = PATH.'/files/';
    $updirst = PATH.'/files/depot/';
    $uploadfile = $updir.'depot/'.$newFileName;
    $fileName = $_FILES['fic_demande']['name'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['fic_demande']['type'];            
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fic_demande']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        header('location:depot/import.php?file='.$newFileName.'&path='.$updirst.'&type='.$fileType);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Hello, Thx for your help. The problem here is before the variable $newFileName. It is in the case. The case except a valid filename and with the asterisk doesn't work.